# DeviceAgent enter_text failed: Timed out after waiting 1.0s for KeyEventCompleted after sending event for

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xcode9, xamarin.uitest

Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException: 
Error appears in pressing the "Done" button or "Enter" from the soft key board while running on real IPAD device.
On simulator, it works fine.

Technologies used:
MAC Book Pro
IDE: Visual Studio Community 2017
Device: IPAD 2017, IOS 11
Xamarin.UITest V 2.1.3
Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent: 0.21.1
Xcode 9

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: HI Derek, No. Still have these issues with latest Xcode and Test Cloud Agent

Comment: Is it possible to share your test code where this is happening? I've hit a similar issue on our integration tests within UITest but on a simulator rather than a device.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following steps or all of them, it usually works for me:

1. Restart VS (VS may be using to many resources and become slow…)
2. Close any REPL terminal, if open.
3. Restart simulator or reconnect device.
4. Remove the DeviceAgent-Runner app from your simulator or device
   (this is an app installed by UITests and will be reinstalled when
   running a UITest)

If it still does not work I usually throw my computer out of the window, that always solves the issue ;-)